# Desearializing Html Object Text to Json in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, json.net

I have a MVC application in ASP.Net core, where I set the text of an HTML paragraph in a model view:

```
<p id="pJsontext" hidden>@Json.Serialize(Model)</p>
```

Next in my .js file I aim to convert (deserialize) the html text to JSON.  I tried

```
var objs = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("pJsontext").innerHTML);
```

but it does not work. The html text when printed to console shows correct serealized Json string. It seems like **JSON.parse** is not compatible with **Json.Serialize**.

Comment: Use `textContent`, not `innerHTML`.

Comment: Tip: You could also just do `<script>const data = @( Json.Serialize( Model ) )</script>` and avoid the need to use `JSON.parse` in script.

Comment: Same result with  textContent and innerText

Comment: The tip worked - thanks for that - but my interest is to find out how to parse the text to JSON.

Comment: **Use your debugger**. Try experimenting with subsets of your rendered JSON to see what makes `JSON.parse` fail. Check for any thrown exceptions as well. What is the value of `objs` when you run your script?

Comment: The debugger does not throw any error. The serialized JSON text: [{"x":1,"y":2,"z":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6}]. The output of JSON.parse: [object object], [object object].

Comment: That output looks like it's working correctly and as-expected (because the objects are clearly being deserialized, and then **reserialized** using an implicit `toString()` in JavaScript). How are you displaying the output of `JSON.parse`, exactly?

Comment: console.log(objs), and also tried console.log(JSON.parse(document.getElementById("pJsontext").innerHTML))

Comment: Use `console.log( "objs = %o", objs )` instead - that will avoid implicit `toString`.

Comment: @Dai it was just that, thanks.

Comment: A bit strange that someone (possibly an expert in this domain)  down voted the post. Understood, the post raised a very basic, but subtle point, which for experts seems very obvious. I spent reasonable time in experimenting and trying a few options, including searching relevant literature, before posting the issue on this forum.